# expose dao class methods to webservice java

Tags: java, jax-ws, dao

I have DAO classes for my DB operations . I wants to expose my DAO class methods to a webservice using JAX-WS. It is a good idea to expose DAO class methods as a webservice methods? Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually it is not a good idea.
Keep your architecture layered:

- Dao is one level
- API (Web Service) is another layer

In the middle (between the dao and API) you usually have a business layer.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. So create a separate class for webservices and use DAO objects inside those classes?

Comment: What do you mean by inside? Inner classes? Usually I prefer to put the different layers in different packages, but it really up to you, how you want your code to be organized.